# asp.net google recaptcha

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I have used google reCaptcha in my asp.net webform application and I follow google`s doc but I get this error :

```
Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid
```

this my code:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
                ID="recaptcha"
                runat="server"
                PrivateKey="your_private_key"
                PublicKey="your_public_key" />
```

I tried different public and private key but the result was same.

Comment: Have you actually generated specific keys for your web application at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/? Presumably you're not actually trying to use "your_private_key" and "your_public_key" as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Indicates your `CAPTCHA` settings are still set to Automatic (S-Drive).

I'll suggest you to read [INPUT ERROR: K: FORMAT OF SITE KEY WAS INVALID.](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/input-error-k-format-of-site-key-was-invalid/).

Answer (score 0):

You must input PrivateKey and PublicKey from recaptcha